# Sbt keeps saying ensime 0.1.5 SNAPSHOT not found, when I'm not using the snapshot

Tags: scala, sbt

I got the following error when trying to build a LiftWeb 2.6 basic project

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#ensime-sbt;0.1.5-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

And thought, alright I'll go into `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt` and change

```
 addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt" % "0.1.5-SNAPSHOT")
```

to

```
addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt" % "0.1.5")
```

I re-ran `sbt` in the project and once again got the same error, I even tried to run `sbt update` but that didn't seem to do anything either.

So now I've been fighting with this thing for a good 15 minutes and it keeps giving me that error, preventing me from continuing starting the project. What do I need to do?

I'm using SBT 0.13.7

Here's the full sbt output in case someone's wondering:

```
╓[ElectricCoffee]─[CoffeeBook-Pro.local]─[2015-04-20, 19:58]─[~/Code/web/test]
╙[$]-[sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ElectricCoffee/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ElectricCoffee/Code/web/test/project
[info] Set current project to Lift 2.6 starter template (in build file:/Users/ElectricCoffee/Code/web/test/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/ElectricCoffee/Code/web/test/}test...
[info] Resolving org.ensime#ensime-sbt;0.1.5-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: org.ensime#ensime-sbt;0.1.5-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/ElectricCoffee/.ivy2/local/org.ensime/ensime-sbt/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ensime/ensime-sbt_2.11_0.13/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/ensime-sbt-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/ensime/ensime-sbt_2.11_0.13/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/ensime-sbt-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/ensime/ensime-sbt_2.11_0.13/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/ensime-sbt-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== staging: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/org/ensime/ensime-sbt_2.11_0.13/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/ensime-sbt-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== releases: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/ensime/ensime-sbt_2.11_0.13/0.1.5-SNAPSHOT/ensime-sbt-0.1.5-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.ensime#ensime-sbt;0.1.5-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      org.ensime:ensime-sbt:0.1.5-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.11)
[warn] 
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#ensime-sbt;0.1.5-SNAPSHOT: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1159)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1182)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1180)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1184)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1179)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1187)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1152)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1130)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ensime#ensime-sbt;0.1.5-SNAPSHOT: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Try this: hit `i` to ignore, then run `reload plugins`, `clean`, `reload return`, still happen?